# Firefox prevent local ip address from redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: firefox, https, http-redirect

I am trying to configure some hardware using the ip address: `192.168.1.251`. For some insane reason Firefox keeps forcing it to `https://192.168.1.251`.

The fact is (a) the address is *never* on the internet; (b) in this case it is the only other machine; and (c) I have no control over how the hardware does its job any way. So what genius decided that they know better and I can’t connect using plain old `http`?

The question is how can I tell Firefox to just shut up and do as it’s told? I have already tried `browser.urlbar.autoFill` and `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` and neither of them works.

Comment: If you try `curl -v http://192.168.1.251` from terminal, what is the response?

Comment: Not in a position to try that just now. I can say that Neither Safari nor Chrome redirect. Oh, and I’m running MacOS, though that shouldn’t make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because at some point a server at this address responded with an [HSTS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).

Click on the icon to the left of the URL in the address bar, then in the dialog click **clear cookies and site data**.  Then confirm in the dialog that appears.